# How to unescape code html using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use the following then it is displayed like html:

```
<h1>heading</h1>
```

This will be the result:

## heading

But how do I unescape all the characters inside `<code>`?

Which results exactly what inside the `<code>`:

```
<h1>heading</h1>
```

Comment: did not understand the question.

Comment: Are you asking how to render the `<` character on screen instead of it being treated as the start of a tag?

Comment: Use `.text()` instead of `.html()` to display it. Or if the text is statically display replace the opening `<` with `&lt`

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript` and `jquery`? You aren't using them in the question.

Comment: unescape or escape???

Comment: @Quentin: There is no code at all, so why worry about what language they want the answer in :)

Comment: If you see Stackoverflow code by inspecting then you'll see everything is inside span. I need something like that!

Answer (score 0):

Either replace the tag syntax with *HTML entities*

```
str = '<foo>';
str = str.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
str; // "&lt;foo&gt;"
```

Or insert it into the page explicitly as text, e.g.

```
parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
```

---

You may also wish to escape single and double quotes to be on the safe side if you plan to use random strings in attributes, too.

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
```

Comment: There's anything inside the `<code>` is that enough to replace just greater and smaller signs only?

Comment: You only need to replace the `<` symbol with `&lt;`, it'll ignore the `>`.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight I included `>` and was considering including quotes too, just in case OP was considering using it in other places

Comment: @PaulS. You only need to replace `<`, though, because that's the start of a tag. If that's not present, the browser will automatically ignore everything else.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight consider `str = '<a --> b>';` put inside `<!-- reasoning: -->`

Comment: @PaulS. I'm sorry, I don't see how that disproves what I've said.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight `<!-- reasoning: <a --> b> -->` will result in a comment followed by `b> -->`

Comment: That's not what the OP is looking for, though.  That's a use case beyond what the OP needs.